# How do you set a custom redirect url when using {% requireLogin %} in Craft 3?

Tags: twig, craftcms

I'm creating a "members only" site using Craft CMS (3) where users must login before they can see the front-end of the site. I'm wondering how you can set a default redirect after a user logs in.

I've got the member only part working using the `{% requireLogin %}` tag at the top of the main layout template, which redirects to `/login`, or in my case `admin/login` since I changed the value of `loginPath` in `config/general.php` to be `/admin/login` (Craft defaults to `/login`). So on every front-end page view, if the user is not logged in, it redirects to the Control Panel (CP) login.

layout.twig:

```
{% requireLogin %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
...
```

config/general.php:

```
...
    'loginPath' => 'admin/login',
...
```

Documentation: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/requirelogin.html

The default functionality, it seems, is that Craft then redirects you to whatever route you came from. So if you hit the site at `/resources/` and it redirects you to the loginPath - after you successfully login it would kick you back to `/resources/`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a "default" redirect, so that no matter what page you come from, after a user logs in, they get redirected to the same place every time.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a year late, but here it goes:

You can use the `postLoginRedirect` general config setting (defined in `/config/general.php`). The [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#postloginredirect) state that this is

> The path that users should be redirected to after logging in from the
>   front-end site. This setting will also come into effect if the user
>   visits the Login page (as specified by the loginPath config setting)
>   when they are already logged in.

Answer (score -1):

The {% requireLogin %} tag doesn’t take any parameters. In fact you should be getting a Twig parsing error if you tried to do

> {% requireLogin 'some/path' %}.

The path is specified by the loginPath config setting, which should support query strings.

Comment: This answer misses the point a bit. OP never suggested using a parameter to `requireLogin`. Also, it would be nice to mention the source of your answer, if you straight up copy paste this from @brandonkelly's response to a GitHub issue at https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1780#issuecomment-309098644